# How can I find historical flight delay data?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, delays

I was on United flight 123 out of Heathrow to Washington Dulles on March 15 2014 and I want to find out what time it actually left. It should have departed at 0735 but was delayed with engine trouble. Now that you can claim for delays I want to find out how long the delay was.

Answer (score 9):

According to [FlightStats](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?airline=%28UA%29%20United%20Airlines&flightNumber=123&departureDate=2014-03-15&x=16&y=8), the flight was delayed 236 minutes.

Scheduled Departure: 7:35 AM - Sat Mar-15-2014
Actual Departure: 12:02 PM - Sat Mar-15-2014

Scheduled Arrival: 12:20 PM - Sat Mar-15-2014
Actual Arrival: 4:16 PM - Sat Mar-15-2014

(You'll need a log in to see the information on that linked site.)